# how to count how many sub-directories a file is in?

Tags: php, path, directory, subdirectory

I have a file called `count.php`.

this is where `count.php` is stored (the absolute path):

`/home/content/61/7475161/html/wordpress/project/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/count.php`

I need a way to count how many sub-folders from the folder `project` are involved in the path.

So in the case above, its four. I've come up with one way:

```
$pathtofile=dirname(__FILE__);

$path_array=explode("/",$pathtofile);

$f_stat=false;
$num_folders=0;

foreach ($path_array as $folder){

if($f_stat===false){

if($folder=="project"){$f_stat=true}

}//end of f_stat false

else{
$num_folders++;
}//end of else

}//end of foreach
//now $num_folders will equal 4 xD
```

I don't think thats the best way to do it, so any suggestions would be awesome. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do strstr with `/project` and count the array elements after explode like this:

```
$path_array=explode('/',strstr($pathtofile, '/project'));
$depth = count($path_array)-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo (substr_count('/',$path) - 7); //> Subtract the number of main dir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dir=glob(directoryname."/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

`$dir return an array` which contains all the subfolder(s) inside the folder.

Comment: Good effort. Is there a possibility to elaborate this any further?